# weird chars on tab completition terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, putty

I am using putty to connect to the a server.

Whenever i press tab.. for file name completion... it puts some weird character..

the ups and downs arrow doesnt work.. and ulimately i end up typing everything.. (the file names..)

for example

```
 directory has file.. foo.py foo.txt

  $python foo.py fo[tab].... i am hoping to see the selections.. (foo.py, foo.txt) and stuff
```

and it shows that...but it also adds a char to the end..and if i try to erase it.. it puts more characters in the end.. :(

Any suggestions  on what might be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: It seems as if it doesn't support autocomplete and history

Comment: @Keyser: Hi i am using putty.. is there any settings in there.. or maybe a different console.. unfortunately i am on windows environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autocomplete and history depends on what environment the server is running. So I'm afraid there's nothing to enable from the client-side. If you can find out what environment the server is running **and** you have write-access, then maybe you could find some environment-specific edits to be made (to config files and such).